# Mosaic plot : empty cells and overlapping labels

Tags: r

I am using vcd library in R in order to perform a mosaic plot of 2 categorical variables, having multiple levels each. I had to customize the function call "mosaic" in order to solve my problem of overlapping labels.

However, I have 2 questions regarding this function mosaic :

1. Why proper line break for long level names is not done automatically, when the simple call is done ? By looking at various vcd tutorial, it looks the function by default should handle that.
2. Why vcd is plotting empty cells ? For example, in my dataframe study_filt, I have no observation with the homosex variable set to "Other". Can it be removed ?

>

```
library(dplyr)
library(vcd)
library(MASS)

load(url("http://bit.ly/dasi_gss_data"))

study=dplyr::select(gss,year,homosex,vetyears)
study=filter(study, year>1974)
study=filter(study, year<1995 | year>2009)
study=group_by(study,year)
study_filt = filter(study,!all(is.na(homosex)) && !all(is.na(vetyears)))
study_filt <- as.data.frame(study_filt)
```

Simple call to the function mosaic

```
vcd::mosaic(data=study_filt,~homosex+vetyears)
```

Customized call to handle long level names

```
vcd::mosaic(data=study_filt,~homosex+vetyears, 
        labeling=labeling_border(
        rot_labels = c(90, 0, 90, 0), 
        just_labels=c("left","left","right","right"),
        tl_varnames = FALSE,
        gp_labels = gpar(fontsize = 9)))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think that `labeling_border` supports automatic line breaks, just rotation and abbreviation as standard strategies for long labels.
2. `mosaic()` shows all `levels(study_filt$homosex)` even if they have zero occurrences. This might be an important piece of information in some scenarios. In your case it is easiest to drop the factor level by calling `factor()` another time: `study_filt$homosex <- factor(study_filt$homosex)`